# Python re.search() not returning full group match

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

ip6 = "1234:0678:0000:0000:00cd:0000:0000:0000"
zeroes = re.search("(:?0000)+", ip6)
print zeroes.group(0)

:0000:0000
```

I'm trying to find the longest sequence of four zeroes separated by colons.  The string contains a sequence of three such groups, yet only two groups are printed.  Why?

EDIT: It's printing :0000:0000 because that's the **first** match in the string -- but I thought regexps always looked for the **longest** match?

Comment: Changed (^0000|:0000) to (:?0000)

Comment: Actually, an NFA regex engine (such as the one in Python) always returns: "the longest, _left-most_" match.

Comment: @ridgerunner Source for that?

Comment: @denniston.t This is explained in Jeffrey Friedl, "Mastering Regular Expressions". Unless the regex engine would find _all_ the matches first, and then choose the longest among those, it is quite natural that it would give you the _first_ match, no matter whether it's the longest of them all.  Among all the matches that start at a given position in the string, it does however give you the longest match, unless you use non-greedy operators such as *?.

Comment: @denniston.t - I got it from: [Mastering Regular Expressions (3rd Edition)](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124 "By Jeffrey Friedl. Best book on Regex - ever!"). Just as drmirror explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer updated to work in Python 2.6:

```
p = re.compile('((:?0000)+)')
longestword = ""
for word in p.findall(ip6):
    if len(word[0])>len(longestword):
        longestword = word[0]
print longestword
```

Comment: That list comprehension gives me a syntax error on the equals sign.  Is it a python3 thing?

Comment: This doesn't work in *my* instance of python 3, so I'd say it's not.

Comment: Yeah I just tested it my interpreter and it didn't work so I've written one which doesn't use a list comprehension

Comment: Python doesn't allow assignments in expressions.  The reason is the common mistake of using `=` when you meant `==` in other languages.

Comment: I actually did mean assignment but I didn't know I couldn't do that in a list comp. Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not stuck on regular-expressions, you could use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

ip6 = "1234:0678:0000:0000:00cd:0000:0000:0000"

longest = 0
for section, elems in groupby(ip6.split(':')):
    if section == '0000':
        longest = len(list(elems))

print longest  # Prints '3', the number of times '0000' repeats the most.
               # you could, of course, generate a string of 0000:... from this
```

I'm sure this can be boiled down to something a bit more elegant, but I think this communicates the point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Python 2.7.3
How about using re.finditer()

```
$ uname -r
3.2.0-4-amd64
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

ip6 = "1234:0678:0000:0000:00cd:0000:0000:0000"

iters = re.finditer("(:?0000)+", ip6)
for match in iters:
    print 'match.group()  -> ',match.group()
```